# Spring data JPA : Transaction for every record is not commited

Tags: jpa, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I need to commit records in a loop with following actions :

- Delete record(Parent+ child) with old status
- Create new record, insert parent + child
  Below deleteOldAndsaveNew() method is called in a loop and i want every time operations inside to be commited.

PFB code snippet:

Calling method:
//Service layer

```
public int updateOldDocumentsFromList(List<DocumentChildDTO> childDocuments) {
            
            int nbDocsUpdated = 0;
            for (DocumentChildDTO docChildDTO : childDocuments) {

            if (docChildDTO .getDocument() != null) {
                DocumentDTO documentDTO = docChildDTO .getDocument();
                Document document =            documentMapper.documentDTOToDocument(documentDTO);
                Document latestDoc = getLatestChildDocument(document);
                

                DocumentStatus statusObsolete = docStatusService.findByName(DocumentStatusType.Obsolete.toString());
                DocumentStatus statusValidated = docStatusService.findByName(DocumentStatusType.Validated.toString());
                boolean isDBDocObsolete = isDBDocObsolete(statusObsolete, latestDoc);
                boolean createDoc = false;
                nbDocsUpdated = documentDAO.deleteObsoleteAndSaveValidatedDoc(docChildDTO, document, latestDoc, statusValidated, isDBDocObsolete,
                        nbDocsUpdated, createDoc);
            }
        }
        LOG.info("End updating olddocouments (nb docs updated: " + nbDocsUpdated + ")");
        return nbDocsUpdated;
    }
```

//Dao layer

```
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) 
 public int deleteObsoleteAndSaveValidatedDoc(DocumentChildDTO docChildDTO, Document document, Document latestDoc,
            DocumentStatus statusValidated, boolean isDBDocObsolete, int nbDocsUpdated, boolean createDoc) {
                DocumentStatus statusObsolete = getOldDocStatus();
                
                if ((latestDoc == null) || isDBDocObsolete(statusObsolete, latestDoc)) {
                    createDoc = true;
                }
                if (isDBDocObsolete(statusObsolete, latestDoc)) {
                    documentDAO.delete(latestDoc);
                }
                DocumentDTO documentDTO;
                if (createDoc) {
                    setters for new document
        
                    // Save the new doc
                    documentDTO = docService.save(document);
                    if (documentDTO == null) {
                        LOG.error("Error");
                    } else {
                        nbDocsUpdated++;
                    }
                    
                
        docChildDTO.setDocument(documentDTO);
                        if (save(docChildDTO) == null) {
                            LOG.error("Error");
                        }
                    }
                return nbDocsUpdated;
            }
    
    Delete document method
    
        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;
        public void delete(Document obsoleteDocument)  {
                  this.entityManager.remove(obsoleteDocument);
                  this.entityManager.flush();
            }
    
        @Transactional
            public void saveDocument(Document document) {
                LOG.debug("Request to save Document : {}", document);
                this.entityManager.persist(document);
                this.entityManager.flush();
               
            }
        
        @Transactional
            public void save(DocumentChild documentChild ) {
                LOG.debug("Request to save documentChild : {}", documentChild );
              documentChildDao.saveAndFlush(documentChild);
               
            }
```

I have used both entity manager and Spring data approaches to see which one works, I can see delete statement and 2 insert statements(parent and child) getting generated and id is also incremented but it is not getting reflected/commited in db.

Does this line  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) not guarantee for commiting the operations inside it for every access of method deleteOldAndsaveNew() ?

Edit: I have removed (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) and tried to use Transactional only on operation which needs to be committed every time .

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Anybody here , please let me know if I am not clear enough? Thanks

Comment: Try to remove the @Transactional from DAO methods.. just use it on the service layer.. where the deleteOldAndsaveNew method is defined

Comment: Thanks  Maciej...removing Transactional from DAO methods not helping. Any other suggestions please ?

Comment: I have tried with removing @Transactional on service class level and put it on only deleteOldAndsaveNew , but no success..

Comment: also, its not a good idea to call flush after every operation.. remove those.. em will flush at the end of transaction..

Comment: ok..removed manual flushes ..I tried to do manual commit ..but got error Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead..so used Spring @Transactional ...but no progress..

Comment: you dont have to do a manual commit.. framework does that for you

Comment: yeah..its dirty way to do it manually as Spring data jpa provides everything..but i thought to make it work :(

Comment: from where do you call deleteOldAndsaveNew? i want to see that method

Comment: I am calling from Service class and class does not have class level Transactional annotation.This method is in Dao layer and annotated with Transactional. I have edited code to include calling method.

Comment: When I enabled transaction logging using in spring boot logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE , I can see transactions getting initiated for Spring data JPA methods like saveAndFlush "ction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor [ main] TRACE  - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush] " within main transaction method deleteObsoleteAndSaveValidatedDoc.But transactions are getting completing  just after unit of work.Would it cause any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks , I am able to solve this . By using below code in a separate class and removed Transactional from class level.

Calling method:

```
public int updateObsoleteDocumentsFromList(List<DocumentChildDTO> childDocuments) {
         LOG.info("Start updating Obsolete documents (nb docs to update: " + childDocuments.size()+ ")" );

         int nbDocsUpdated = 0;
        try {
            DocumentStatus statusObsolete = docStatusService.findByName(StatusType.Old.toString());
            Status statusValidated = docStatusService.findByName(StatusType.Validated.toString());
            for (DocumentChildDTO docChildDTO : childDocuments) {
                if (docChildDTO .getDocument() != null) {
                    DocumentDTO documentDTO = docChildDTO .getDocument();
                    Document document = documentMapper.documentDTOToDocument(documentDTO);
                    nbDocsUpdated = documentDAO.deleteObsoleteAndSaveValidatedDoc(docChildDTO, document, statusValidated,  
                            nbDocsUpdated, statusObsolete);
                }
            }
        }

        return nbDocsUpdated;
    }
```

Called method(in separate class)

```
@Transactional
    public Integer deleteObsoleteAndSaveValidatedDoc(DocumentChildDTO docChildDTO, Document document,
            DocumentStatus statusValidated, int nbDocsUpdated ,DocumentStatus statusObsolete) {

        Document latestDoc = getLatestChildDocument(document);
        boolean isDBDocObsolete = isDBDocObsolete(statusObsolete, latestDoc);
        boolean createDoc = false;
        DocumentDTO documentDTO;
        if ((latestDoc == null) || isDBDocObsolete) {
            createDoc = true;
        }

        if (isDBDocObsolete) {
            documentChildDao.deleteChildDocumentByDocId(latestDoc.getId());
            deleteDocumentById(latestDoc.getId());
        }
        if (createDoc) {
            document.setUpdateDate(new Date());
            document.setStatus(statusValidated);
            document.setIsObsolete(false);

            documentDTO = saveDocument(document);
            if (documentDTO == null) {
                LOG.error("Cannot create document " + document.getName());
            } else {
                nbDocsUpdated++;
            }
            docChildDTO.setDocument(documentDTO);
            if (documentChildDao.save(docChildDTO) == null) {
                LOG.error("Cannot create child document " + docChildDTO.getNameChild());
            }

        return nbDocsUpdated;
    }
```

Thanks.